# Click to toggle class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a click event which will toggle a class on a HTML element.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<navigation class="navigation" v-bind:class="{'class1': class1}">
```

And in my data method I have:

```
            data: {
                class1: false 
            },
```

However nothing happens when I click the element, I dont even get an error in the console. Perhaps I havent include the right version of vueJS into my code in order to use event handlers?

You can see a codepen here with the full code: https://codepen.io/fennefoss/pen/BGOywz

Answer (score 0):

I don´t see a click handler in your Navigation?

```
<navigation @click="class1 = !class1" class="navigation" v-bind:class="{'class1': class1}">
```

This will for example toggle the class on click.

Comment: Do I not need a method or anything?, I cant get any thing to happen. I have also tried some of the simple examples on this page: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html however I cant get anything to work :/

Comment: @MikkelFennefoss I suggest you to watch a entry course or something because you seem really confused, there are a lot of them out there, the `v-bind:class` for example binds a css class to the element if a certain condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve it, by using the following code:

```
<navigation id="mobile-toggle"
    v-bind:class="{ active: showMobileMenu }"
    v-on:click="showMobileMenu = !showMobileMenu">something
</navigation>

data: {
    showMobileMenu: false
},
```

Comment: Gongratz, but isnt that exactly my solution? :D